# What is the difference between Big O and asymptotic notation?

Tags: complexity-theory, terminology

Are the two interchangeable or is there a difference?

Answer (score 1):

Bachmann–Landau notation or asymptotic notation is collection of notations one of which is Big-$O$. So they are not interchangeable, because as asymptotic notation also is known little-$o$, big-$\Omega$, big-$\Theta$ etc.

[Historically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Matters_of_notation) this symbol was introduced by German  mathematician [Paul Bachmann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Gustav_Heinrich_Bachmann) and then adopted by German number  theoretician  [Edmund Landau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmund_Landau) and American mathematician [L.E. Dickson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonard_Eugene_Dickson) . Big-$O$ was shorthand for function rate of growth, which is called its ***order***.

History also can be viewed in the book by Florian Cajori - A history of mathematical notations-Dover Publications (1993), page 31.